# Flask extension not registered in app.extensions

Tags: python, flask

I want to access some extensions registered on my Flask app. I tried using `app.extensions`, but some of the extensions that I initialized aren't in the dict.

```
from flask import current_app
current_app.extensions.get(plugin_name)
```

`extensions.py`:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension
from flask_images import Images
from flask_redis import FlaskRedis
from flask_plugins import PluginManager

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
mail = Mail()
toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension()
images = Images()
redis = FlaskRedis()
plugin_manager = PluginManager()
```

`main.py`:

```
def configure_extensions(app):
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    mail.init_app(app)
    toolbar.init_app(app)
    images.init_app(app)
    redis.init_app(app)
    plugin_manager.init_app(
        app,
        plugin_folder="app/plugins",
        plugin_import_path='app.plugins',
    )
```

When I look at `current_app.extensions`, I only see some of the extensions. `plugin_manager` and `toolbar` are not in the list.

```
>>> for key in app.extensions: print(key)
migrate
mail
images
sqlalchemy
redis
```

Why aren't some extensions registered in `app.extensions`? Am I initializing them incorrectly? How can I get the extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extensions aren't required to add themselves to `app.extensions`, it's provided as an optional convenience. Apparently, those extensions don't add themselves. If you want that, consider submitting a patch to the relevant projects.

You don't need to use `app.extensions` to access the extension instances. Instead, import the instances you created, such as `from myapp.extensions import db`. That's the point of being able to create them separately from initializing them. When used in an app context (such as during a request), the objects will know what app to use.