# Flask-Login extension fail to register, login Manager not defined

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am facing an issue where my app is not able to recognise '@login_manager' decorator even though I have imported login_manager object created from extensions.py. I tried to debug the issue by printing out the package extensions that are configured in the app and it seems that login_manager is not included. Maybe that could be the cause of the failure. I have also read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545133/flask-extension-not-registered-in-app-extensions) posted question, but I felt it wasn't a satisfying answer. Given that login_manager.init(app), is recommended in the official documentation found [here](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Hope someone who is really experience in flask to be able to help me out here. Thank you!

app.py

```
from flask_login import login_required, current_user
from flask import Flask, render_template,request
from amazonreviews import main_func as m
import os
import json

def create_app():
   app = Flask(__name__)
   with app.app_context():
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://///somepath/abc.sqlite3'
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
        app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

        #Initialise extensions
        register_extensions(app)

        return app

def register_extensions(app):
        from extensions import db
        from extensions import migrate
        from extensions import login_manager

        db.init_app(app)
        migrate.init_app(app,db)
        login_manager.init_app(app)

        for key in app.extensions:
            print(key)

app = create_app()
#A user loader tells Flask-Login how to find a specific user from the ID that is stored in      their session cookie

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
        from model import User
        # since the user_id is just the primary key of our user table, use it in the query for the user
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))
```

extensions.py

```
#Import external packages and create external objects
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_migrate import Migrate


migrate = Migrate()
db = SQLAlchemy()
login_manager = LoginManager()
```

Print key from extension output:
[image: Print key output]

@login_manager decorator not recognised:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In that code, `login_manager` isn't defined until `register_extensions` is called.

Assuming the instance of `login_manager` is created in `extensions`, you might be able to hoist the import up to the top. E.g.,

```
import json
from extensions import login_manager

...

@login_manager.user_loader
...
```